# AngularJS - how to iteare over object keys?

Tags: javascript

I want to initialize like this:

```
vm.line0 = 1;
vm.line1 = 1;
...
```

So I make an iteration like this in angular:

```
angular.forEach(modules, function (value, key) {
    var i = key;
    var temp = 'line' + i;
    vm.temp= 1;
});
```

However, it seems a big mistake. But how can I get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the desired result is, but missed syntax is related to javascript. It has nothing to do with Angular.

To access a property of an object by name (which is hold in a string variable) you should use brackets

```
angular.forEach(modules, function (value, key) {
    var i = key;
    var temp = 'line' + i;
    vm[temp] = 1;
});
```

However, as a piece of advice, why not to use array for grouping elements that should be iterated? This will simplify lots of things later

```
vm.lines = [];

angular.forEach(modules, function (value, key) {
    vm.lines[key] = key;
});
```